# removing special character

Tags: sed, awk, grep

How do I remove the greater than < sign from the beginning of the line ^

```
file.txt
> INSERT INTO
> INSERT INTO

Expected:
INSERT INTO
INSERT INTO
```

Comment: a  greater than sign is `>` , not `<`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F'>' '{print $2}' file.txt
```

Comment: if you have extra ">" in the rest of your string, it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
sed 's/^> //' inputfile
```

Comment: @shantanuo: It works for me. In what way does it not work for you?

Comment: @shantanuo: It should work (and is IMHO the "canonical" way to do it), and I've tried: it does work. Maybe you mistyped something ? It's important that the `'` is the one to the right of the `:` key on an US keyboard. The `^> ` (note the space) means "> at the beginning of the line (the very first character), followed by a space".

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk '{gsub(/^[ \t]*>[ \t]*/,"")}1' file
awk '{$1=""}1' file
```

sed

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*>[ \t]*//' file
```

cut

```
cut -d" " -f2- file
```

or using the shell

```
while read -r line; do  echo ${line##>}; done < file
```